# Powershell add multiple users/groups NTFS permissions?

Tags: powershell

Trying to add Full Control to a few users to a folder in Powershell have the following, runs with no errors but only adds the last "rule" to the folder. What am I doing wrong?

```
$acl = Get-Acl E:\MyFolder
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("DOMAIN\john.smith","FullControl","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("DOMAIN\Domain Admins","FullControl","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("DOMAIN\Folder-Admins","FullControl","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
(Get-Item E:\MyFolder).SetAccessControl($acl)
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried running the exact same code as you like so :

```
$acl = Get-Acl C:\temp
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("some_user","FullControl","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("other_user","FullControl","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
(Get-Item C:\Temp).SetAccessControl($acl)
```

And it added both to my folder so it doesn't seem to be an issue with the code itself, have you checked if maybe the domain and names were correct and that you are authorized to assign such permissions to that user/group?

For references i'm using Powershell version : 5.1.17763.771, and I ran those lines with local accounts and not domain accounts as I don't have access to a domain right now.

Comment: Hmm?? I will investigate further. Thanks for the clarity

Answer (score 1):

You might try the [NTFS PowerShell module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/1abd77a5-9c0b-4a2b-acef-90dbb2b84e85), it makes things much easier and is quite capable.

A command to add full access would look something like:

```
Add-NTFSAccess -Path <path> -Account <Account> -AccessRights FullControl -AccessType Allow
```